# Woocommerce show product brand in cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I trying to do is showing brand name under product title in cart page, for testing I didn't use `function` in function.php, and did direct change to `cart.php` but no success:

```
$product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
$brands = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'pwb-brand' );
foreach( $brands as $brand ) echo '<p>'.$brand->name.'</p>';
```

but nothing shows, I used `var_dump($brands)` in return:

> object(WP_Error)#37768 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) {
> ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "Invalid category" } }
> ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } ["additional_data":protected]=> array(0)
> { } }

I also tried other ways:

```
wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_brand', ['fields' => 'names'])
```

return nothing and same error.
What I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invalid_taxonomy` means there is no such `taxonomy` with `pwb-brand` or `product_brand` name, actually it depends on which plugin or theme are you using, for finding correct `taxonomy` name go to plugin page, check for your `brand` plugin or if it's on your theme check functions, but simple way is go to brand page in admin check `url`, for example:

```
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=ourbrandname&post_type=our
//-------------------------------^
```

This is your target `taxonomy`, now try:

```
wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'ourbrandname', ['fields' => 'names'])
```

Comment: Thanks solved with `wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'store', ['fields' => 'names'])`